# missing/replaced arrow glyphs in HTML fonts

Tags: html, css, unicode, fonts

This is a minor presentation thing that has bugged me for ages:
http://gyazo.com/e5bed138e234fef7f570bd36edee3edd.png

Checkout how the left and up arrows inserted with `&rarr;` and `&uarr;` are the wrong size and style (this is Monaco in Apple Webkit). From my understanding this is because the font doesn't support these glyphs so it's falling back to another one. But why?? It happens with lots of standard fonts, I can't believe that Monaco doesn't have left and up unicode arrow glyphs.

Anyone else come across this and if so is there any kind of solution or workaround? Couldn't find one on Stack Overflow yet!

**Update:** I'm using glyphs because you can do cool things like fade the colours, and it's lightweight - they are like a free graphics library. As suggested by Thirty dot using sans-serif is the best to go with, it's good in Webkit but Firefox still looks wrong. I'm not sure the exact unicode values that entities such as `&larr;` and `&uarr;` point to but I'm guessing in some browsers they are mismatched. Shame.

Comment: Workaround: Use images to represent the buttons instead. It's not important that they're text, is it? Specifically, use a CSS Sprite so that all the buttons are contained inside one image.

Comment: you should answer with this ^^ it's a good solution

Comment: You could use an image for the arrows instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Workaround:**
Use images to represent the buttons instead. It's not important that they're text, is it? Specifically, use a [CSS Sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) so that all the buttons are contained inside one image.

**Another Idea:**
You could try `font-family: sans-serif` on just the buttons. `sans-serif` usually defaults to a safe font with many different symbols available. Hopefully, this font will have all the glyphs you require. You should also check you're using glyphs from the "same area" of Unicode.

Also, line your buttons up properly: at the moment, they like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll mark this as answered because I think using glyphs is flawed (but due to browser implementation not concept). The misalignment is caused by the glyph line-heights in Firefox, honest!